# Apache HTTP Client - Download HTML only

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I have implemented an Apache Http Client in my android application, I only need to download the actual HTML of a page, not of the images, scripts or css. Is there a way I can turn those off? Something like this..

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setCssEnabled(false);
client.setJs(false);
client.setImages(false);
```

I know those methods don't exist, but you can probably understand what i'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for HTML, you mean HTML source or HTML text ?

Comment: I just want the client to only download the HTML, None of the images or scripts or anything to save bandwidth. The html is parsed and put into android views (not displayed in a webview) so there is no need for any of the visual stuff which takes up a lot of data and makes the request time a lot longer.

Comment: So to answer your question, just the source haha.

Comment: As long as you don't open the page in browser, CSS / JS / Images are just reference links ( text ) . You can still read the content of HTML without loading those resources .

Comment: So when I run client.execute(URL); The HttpResponse hasn't downloaded the images or css or anything, just the source?

Comment: Give it a try. Won't hurt you.